# Svn slave HEAD higher than repository HEAD

Tags: svn

My office just moved and a new svn server has been set with a different URL and different users credentials. Instead of refetching all the repository, I have decided to update my username password and the URL of the repository as following

```
svn switch --relocate http://192.168.1.3:18090/svn/my_repo --username blabla --password blabla123 http://192.168.7.41:18090/svn/my_repo
```

When I run `svn log`, I can see that the URL has been successfuly updated

But now when I try `svn update`, it throw the following message

```
svn: E000000: A reported revision is higher than the current repository HEAD revision.
```

So I guess the svn repository has been reset.

How can I update from the new repository?

Comment: i think your company didnt take the latest revision while relocating

Answer (score 0):

Most probably as @sheldonCooper (nice nick bro :D) suggested while relocating the repo the administrators did not get the latest (one or more) revision/s from the original repository.

Or another version was pushed to the old repository and you updated to it before switching. What the error message actually says is that your local revision seems higher than the one on the (new) server.

You can do the following:

I. Bad (better to contact the admins first :D)

1. Switch to the old repo.
2. Make an export of the code from the repo.
3. Revert the working copy to the previous revision or the revision that matches the one in the new repo.
4. Switch the repo again to the new repo.
5. Try `svn update` or a `compare` so you know that the file version match.
6. Copy/Paste the export you created over the current code base
7. Commit

II. A bit better

1. Make an export of your current code base.
2. Replace all files with the new repo version
3. Copy/Paste the exported files over the new working copy
4. Commit

Comment: I understood the error message, i'm searching for solution now

Comment: Ask the repo admins for some feedback. :)

Comment: 1. Old repo is dead, 2.I don't want to replace all the files. My plan was to just update the url and account credential, not download the whole project

Comment: I think your goal is not possible now, and you're in cleanup mode.